# Why is the English word "pepper" spelt with a double 'p' when it comes from Latin "piper" (with no double 'p')?

Tags: etymology, orthography

The English word "pepper" comes from Latin word "piper". But why is there a double 'p' in the English word, when there is no double 'p' in the Latin word? Where does the English spelling of the word "pepper" come from?

Comment: To me, it looks like *peper* would be pronounced like  *peeper*.  Compare the spellings of *capper* and *caper*.  Or *sobber* and *sober*.

Comment: Once again, it must come as a terrible shock to learn that English spelling (a) is not consistent, (b) does not follow common spelling rules, (c) has only contradictory relations with the pronunciation of English words, and (d) was intended to write a different language altogether (Middle English). This may explain some things; it certainly answers any questions about **why** any English word is spelled or pronounced the way it is.

Comment: If you consult an etymological dictionary, there's lots of variation back to Sanskrit *pippali*. Some may match etymological laws but there's a limit to what can be explained.